# Why doesn`t list[:][0] get me the first row of the list?

Tags: python, list, row

For the following:

```
list=[[2, 3, 5], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Why does `[list[0][0], list[1][0]]` represent the first row ([2, 7]), but the command `list[:][0]` or `list[0:2][0]` returns the first column ([2, 3, 5])?

The way I see it `list[:][0]` should get all the possible values for the first parameter (that is 0 and 1) and 0 for the second, meaning it would return the first row. Instead what it does is return the first column and I can't understand why.

Comment: In the future, please do research before asking a question.

Comment: It's best to reserve the row-column abstraction to 2-dimensional data structures. Python lists do not have rows and columns. They can contain anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, the `[a:b:c]` syntax creates a new list. That is,

```
list = [1,2,3]
print(list[:])
```

is going to print a list, not a value.

Therefore, when you say `list[:][0]` you are making a copy of the original list (`list[:]`) and then accessing item 0 within it.

Of course you know, item 0 of the original list (`list[0]`) is another list.

I think you want:

```
[sl[0] for sl in list]
```

**Elaboration:**

This is called a "comprehension." It is a compact special syntax for generating lists, dicts, and tuples by processing or filtering other iterables. Basically {..}, [..], and (..) with an expression inside involving a `for` and optionally an `if`. Naturally, you can have multiples (like [x for x in y for y in z]) of the for, and multiples of the if.

In your case, it's pretty obvious you want a list. So `[]`. You want to make the list by taking the first item from each sublist. So `[sl[0] for sl in list]`.

Here's a more-detailed article: http://carlgroner.me/Python/2011/11/09/An-Introduction-to-List-Comprehensions-in-Python.html

Comment: I understand the explanation and the solution you gave works! I just don`t understand the syntax. Could you elaborate a little bit? Thanks!